# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.heartapp.Member2 [duplicate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Everything works well until I retrieve data from my database, I want to know what seems to be the problem and the ways how to fix this. I really need help for this. It seems like the error occurs in the line 43 of the `History.java`. Thank you so much for your response.

Here is the error code from `Logcat`

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.heartapp, PID: 31504
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.heartapp.Member2
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.example.heartapp.History$1.onDataChange(History.java:43)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
2022-11-15 20:38:26.810 31504-31504 Process                 com.example.heartapp                 I  Sending signal. PID: 31504 SIG: 9
2022-11-15 20:38:26.854  1476-1670  InputDispatcher         pid-1476                             E  channel 'd52c022 com.example.heartapp/com.example.heartapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (31504) for package com.example.heartapp ----------------------------
2022-11-15 20:38:26.859  1476-1670  InputDispatcher         pid-1476                             E  channel '5fc9a49 com.example.heartapp/com.example.heartapp.History (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2022-11-15 20:38:26.881  1476-2965  WindowManager           pid-1476                             E  win=Window{d52c022 u0 com.example.heartapp/com.example.heartapp.MainActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
2022-11-15 20:38:26.908  2286-15179 DollieAdapterService    pid-2286                             E  notifyActivityState pkg:com.example.heartapp/com.example.heartapp.History state:20 fg:false mUid:10127
```

Here is my `History.java`

```
package com.example.heartapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class History extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Member2> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

        String email=getIntent().getStringExtra("keyemail");

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.History);
        databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(email);
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter=new MyAdapter(this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Member2 user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Member2.class);
                    list.add(user);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Here is my `Memeber2.java`

```
package com.example.heartapp;

public class Member2 {
    String age;
    String sex;
    String stp1;
    String stp2a;
    String stp2b;
    String stp2c;
    String stp2d;
    String stp2e;
    String stp2f;
    String stp2g;
    String stp2h;
    String stp2i;
    String stp3;
    String stp4a;
    String stp4b;
    String stp4c;
    String stp4d;
    String stp4e;
    String stp4f;
    String stp4g;
    String stp4h;
    String stp5;
    String result;
    String tips;

    public Member2() {
    }

    public String getage() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getsex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public String getstp1() {
        return stp1;
    }

    public String getstp2a() {
        return stp2a;
    }

    public String getstp2b() {
        return stp2b;
    }

    public String getstp2c() {
        return stp2c;
    }

    public String getstp2d() {
        return stp2d;
    }

    public String getstp2e() {
        return stp2e;
    }

    public String getstp2f() {
        return stp2f;
    }

    public String getstp2g() {
        return stp2g;
    }

    public String getstp2h() {
        return stp2h;
    }

    public String getstp2i() {
        return stp2i;
    }

    public String getstp3() {
        return stp3;
    }

    public String getstp4a() {
        return stp4a;
    }

    public String getstp4b() {
        return stp4b;
    }

    public String getstp4c() {
        return stp4c;
    }

    public String getstp4d() {
        return stp4d;
    }

    public String getstp4e() {
        return stp4e;
    }

    public String getstp4f() {
        return stp4f;
    }

    public String getstp4g() {
        return stp4g;
    }

    public String getstp4h() {
        return stp4h;
    }

    public String getstp5() {
        return stp5;
    }

    public String getresult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String gettips() {
        return tips;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `MyAdapter.java`

```
package com.example.heartapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<Member2> list;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Member2> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Member2 user = list.get(position);
        holder.age.setText(user.getage());
        holder.result.setText(user.getresult());
        holder.sex.setText(user.getsex());
        holder.stp1.setText(user.getstp1());
        holder.stp2a.setText(user.getstp2a());
        holder.stp2b.setText(user.getstp2b());
        holder.stp2c.setText(user.getstp2c());
        holder.stp2d.setText(user.getstp2d());
        holder.stp2e.setText(user.getstp2e());
        holder.stp2f.setText(user.getstp2f());
        holder.stp2g.setText(user.getstp2g());
        holder.stp2h.setText(user.getstp2h());
        holder.stp2i.setText(user.getstp2i());
        holder.stp3.setText(user.getstp3());
        holder.stp4a.setText(user.getstp4a());
        holder.stp4b.setText(user.getstp4b());
        holder.stp4c.setText(user.getstp4c());
        holder.stp4d.setText(user.getstp4d());
        holder.stp4e.setText(user.getstp4e());
        holder.stp4f.setText(user.getstp4f());
        holder.stp4g.setText(user.getstp4g());
        holder.stp4h.setText(user.getstp4h());
        holder.stp5.setText(user.getstp5());
        holder.tips.setText(user.gettips());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView age, result, sex, stp1, stp2a, stp2b, stp2c, stp2d, stp2e, stp2f, stp2g, stp2h, stp2i, stp3, stp4a, stp4b, stp4c, stp4d, stp4e, stp4f, stp4g, stp4h, stp5, tips;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            age=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
            result=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
            sex=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSex);
            stp1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp1);
            stp2a=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2a);
            stp2b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2b);
            stp2c=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2c);
            stp2d=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2d);
            stp2e=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2e);
            stp2f=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2f);
            stp2g=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2g);
            stp2h=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2h);
            stp2i=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp2i);
            stp3=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp3);
            stp4a=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4a);
            stp4b=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4b);
            stp4c=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4c);
            stp4d=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4d);
            stp4e=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4e);
            stp4f=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4f);
            stp4g=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4g);
            stp4h=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp4h);
            stp5=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstp5);
            tips=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTips);
        }
    }
}
```

Here also the structure in my database

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question unless OP edits it to include the text version of the code and output

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one or more of the child nodes of the path you read are not full `Member2` object, but rather is just a string value. The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to print the key of the snapshot just before you try to get the object from it:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i("Firebase",                               //  Log the key and value
              "Reading Member2 from "+dataSnapshot.getKey() //  to know where the
              +", value="+dataSnapshot.getValue()           //  problem is in your
            );                                              //  data
            Member2 user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Member2.class);
            list.add(user);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException();                          //  never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: I have resolve the problem, there are excess items in the Database Reference (email), I deleted those and the program works perfectly as expected. Thank you for your response.